# React component render twice using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having a really hard time to figure out what's happening when there is nothing being used to trigger re-render the component.

`Events.js` Component renders twice when I remove the `useState()` from the `Event.js` it renders once, but I need to keep it. when I use `useEffect()` inside Event components, renders fourth time.

I just kept the dummy data to give you to fill the emptiness and tried to remove `React.memo`, nothing happens. the problem is with the `Event.js` component I believe. I'm also using the Context API, but forth time rendering is too much.

useEffect inside `App.js` is getting some value from the localStorage, I can't access that direct 'cause the value is undefined by default

sandbox code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/event-manager-reactjs-nbz8z?file=/src/Pages/Events/Events.js 
The `Events.js` file is located on `/Pages/Events/Events.js`

example code is below

Event.js ( child component )

```
function Events() {

    // Sate Managing
    const [allEvents, setAllEvents]   = React.useState(null);
    console.log('Rendering EventsJs', allEvents);

    React.useEffect(() => {
         setAllEvents(['apple', 'banana']);
    }, []);



    return (
        <div className="events">

                { console.log('Event Rendered.js =>') }

        </div>
    )
}


export default React.memo(Events, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
        return true;
} );
```

App.js ( parent component )

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const [userId, setUserId] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUserId(1);
  }, []);


  // Login

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>

      <Navigation />

      <Route  path='/events' component={Events} />

      {console.log('App Rendered')}

    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: When you remove which `useState` and why are you using useEffect this way ? You could just set the userId to 1 directly by doing `useState(1)`

Comment: What if remove useEffect in App, and set initital value for useState for 1?, because every time you change state, component will rerender if state value was changed, and you changed it from null to 1

Comment: Try to replace `()=>false` by `()=>true` to tell your memo that `props`are equal.

Comment: @StasMercer useEffect is getting some value from the localStorage, I can't that direct 'cause the value is undefined by default

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I've already tried, but nothing happens here, basically Event component renders 6th time, but I remove alot of code and still 2 time

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine after all thing I've tried then I check the memo here

Comment: I update the question, please have a look!

Comment: @BloodyLogic, your problem is the parent `app` component generates new instances of the `events` component which breaks memoization because you did not pass any `props` to your `events` component to apply `are equal` method.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I really appreciate your time, I have nothing to pass the event.js, I tried memo if maybe this helped. I updated the question, thanks!

Comment: Do you have [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled?

Comment: @AjeetShah StrictMode even don't work, thanks!

Comment: setAllEvents in the effect is pointless, you can do `React.useState(['apple', 'banana']);` and prevent one re render after mount. Lots of people already told you that you're using React.memo wrong (I suggest leaving out the second argument). Other than that there is no code showing that would cause 6 re renders so without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (not a code dump with debug request) there is not much anyone can do.

Comment: @AjeetShah I deploy the code on sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nbz8z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @HMR sorry to hear it. here you can find the live code example https://codesandbox.io/s/nbz8z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: remove strictmode from [index](https://codesandbox.io/s/nbz8z?file=/src/index.js), remove strictmode from [Event](https://codesandbox.io/s/nbz8z?file=/src/Pages/Events/Events.js) and remove the effect on mount and Events will only render once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is working fine. It is rendering as it should. As we know:

> A React component re-renders whenever its *props* or *state* change.

And [react component lifecycle order](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram) is:

1. Initial props/state --> render --> DOM update --> mounted
2. props/state changed --> render --> DOM update --> updated ... so on

In the example below, it is rendering **2 times** and that's correct:

- First one (first console.log) is due to initial render with *state* as `[]`
- Second one (second console.log) is due to *state* change (caused by useEffect) to `['apple', 'banana']`

```
function Events() {
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = React.useState([]);
  console.log('Event Rendered', allEvents);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllEvents(['apple', 'banana']);
  }, []);

  return <>Events</>;
}
```

About using React.memo:

> [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) only checks for *props* changes. If your function component wrapped in React.memo has a *useState* or *useContext* Hook in its implementation, **it will still rerender when state or context change**.

You can not skip re-render using `React.memo` due to change in *state*. You can only optimize to skip re-rendering caused by change in *props*.

But in the example above, you don't have props passed from the parent component, the only props passed to `Events` are those passed by [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) i.e. route props. So, there is no need to use React.memo.

Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-too-much-render-zumle?file=/src/App.js), check the console.logs. You will see only 3 logs: "App render", "Event render with initial state", "Event render with new state".

---

#### EDIT:

If we remove [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) from *index.html*, and add below console.logs in components:

```
App.js --> console.log('App rendered')
Evenets.js --> console.log('Event rendered', allEvents, isLoading) // (allEvents and isLoading are state variables here)
```

And go to http://localhost:3000, we see 1 log:

```
App Rendered
```

Now click on "Events", we see 3 logs:

```
1: Event Rendered, [], true
2: Event Rendered, [{}, ... 54 items], true
3: Event Rendered, [{}, ... 54 items], false
```

which is **correct behavior** (refer lifecycles order written above):

- 1st log: render with initial state (`[]`, `true`)
- 2nd log: render with new allEvents (`54 items`) and old isLoading (`true`)
- 3rd log: render with old allEvents (`54 items`) and new isLoading (`false`)

---

Below are the right questions to ask now:

#### Question1:

**Why 2nd and 3rd render (log) are separate, should not they be batched (merged) and applied together as they are written in the same function?**

```
fetch('url').then(() => {
  // ... code here
  setAllEvents([...events])
  setLoading(false)
})
```

**Answer:**

**No, they will not be batched in above code**. As explained by [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950):

> This is implementation detail and may change in future versions.

> In current release, they will be batched together if you are inside a React event handler. React batches all setStates done during a React event handler, and applies them just before exiting its own browser event handler.

> With current version, several setStates outside of event handlers (e.g. in network responses) will not be batched. So you would get two re-renders in that case.

> There exists a **temporary API to force batching**. If you write `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => { this.fn1(); });` then both calls will be batched. But we expect to remove this API in the future and instead batch everything by default.

So, you can write (inside fetch's then), if you want, *it will save 1 render*:

```
ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
  setAllEvents([...events])
  setLoading(false)
})
```

#### Question2:

**What's React event handler in above quote?**

**Answer:** `foo` in example below. These 2 set states will be batched.

```
const foo = () => {
  setAllEvents([
    { _id: '5ede5af03915bc469a9d598e', title: 'jfklsd', },
  ])
  setLoading(false) 
}

<button onClick={foo}>CLICK</button>
```

#### Question3:

**Does it update HTML DOM as many times as it renders (prints console.log)?**

**Answer:** **No**. React compares calculated virtual DOMs before updating real DOM, so only those changes are applied to real DOM which are required to update the UI.

#### Question4:

**Why was rendering doubled when we use `StrictMode`?**

**Answer:** Yes, `StrictMode` will intentionally double invoke "render" and some other lifecycle methods to [detect side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build.

Comment: I think you're closer to the Answer, can you please now look into my code. I appreciate your answer, thanks!  https://codesandbox.io/s/event-manager-reactjs-nbz8z?file=/src/Pages/Events/Events.js

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you, you're the real solver!

Comment: Hopefully, in future versions of react, we won't even need to use `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` as setStates outside react event handlers will be batched too.

Answer (score 2):

Well actually this is caused by your usage of `React.memo`, its second parameter is called `areEqual`, and you pass in `() => false`, so you are basically telling React that the props are always changing. Therefore whenever App rerenders, Events rerenders too.

Comment: I've tried every possible way, but didn't help me, I updated the question!

Answer (score 1):

You should let `React.memo` check for prop changes. By passing `() => false` you are actually telling that its props always change (they are **never** equal).

```js
export default React.memo(Events);
```

Here's a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-frog-gmvvc?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your hard works, but that didn't solve my problem!

Comment: @BloodyLogic, please could you reproduce your code via `codepen` or other environments.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine The Event.js file is located In Pages/Events/Events.js  on https://codesandbox.io/s/nbz8z?file=/src/App.js